# How to create a string search with numbers and letters?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to figure out how to create a search string that has both letters and numbers in it.  For example CC37000 and CCL370191.

How do I do a search to between the two, but only get CC37000, while only using the first three characters?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question may attract more attention and help if you include examples of what you have tried or documentation you have consulted. Also, you included both a v2.0 and v3.0 tag - please clarify which version you are working with, or if you explicitly need a cross-version compatible script.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, can't add a comment since I haven't got enough reputation.
@Ansgar Wiechers: You're right, but he's trying to get CC37000, not CCL370191. The regular expression should be like :

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $str = 'CC37000', 'CCL370191'
PS C:\Windows\system32> $str -match '^CC3'`
CC37000
```

Or

```
$str -match '^[a-z]{2}\d'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to match only strings that start with only two letters:

```
PS C:\> $s = 'CC37000', 'CCL370191'
PS C:\> $s
CC37000
CCL370191
PS C:\> $s -match '^[a-z]{2}[^a-z]'
CC37000
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `^` matches the beginning of a string
- `[a-z]` is a character class matching only letters. PowerShell comparisons are by default case insensitive, so you don't have to use `[a-zA-Z]` to match uppercase letters too (unless you use the `-cmatch` operator).
- `{2}` matches the preceeding expression exactly 2 times.
- `[^a-z]` is another character class, but the caret at the beginning inverts its meaning, so it matches any character *except* a letter.